# Finding a user and adding an id to its friends array property

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

When the "Follow user" button is clicked (in Frienddetail component) the addPeopleFollow function is invoked. With this function I want to store the id of the user clicked (the one you are trying to follow) in the friends Array property of the user that is logged in/clicked on my database.

My database has a user collection with all users in with per user this:

```
_id:5eff397b70d78284c8c45186
friends:Array
username:"charlestryingout"
password:"$2b$10$CYMyPx10gk0jO5XoazcrSO32Ng37qoyU6uXkkeaswQ5KWm7k7ooym"
__v:0
```

For example: if user with id = 5eff397b70d78284c8c45186 clicks the other user to follow with id = 5eff397b70d78284c8c45187, then I would want to have this as a result in my database:

```
_id:5eff397b70d78284c8c45186
friends:Array[5eff397b70d78284c8c45187]
username:"charlestryingout"
password:"$2b$10$CYMyPx10gk0jO5XoazcrSO32Ng37qoyU6uXkkeaswQ5KWm7k7ooym"
__v:0
```

I have coded the content of the addPeopleFollow function (axios request) and managed to get it working (I can see the console.logs in the .then in my console). Feel free to suggest changes if you think it is incomplete.

---

**My question:**

Can someone help me writing the backend (first version below)?
I would first need to seach in my users list for the user currently logged in (via getUser function this should work). When that specific user is found I would have to add the id in its friends array property. My first idea would be to .findByIdAndUpdate({_id:iduser}) but then I don't know how to push the id into the existing friends array (updating part).

Could you please write out the full code (think just backend but feel free to suggest changes in frontend aswell. I am using Node/Mongoose/MongoDB/React

---

**Front-end React**

```
addPeopleFollow(idpeopleyoufollow){
    Axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/friends`,
        data: qs.stringify(idpeopleyoufollow),
        headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        withCredentials: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("charles")
        console.log(idpeopleyoufollow)
        console.log("charles")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response)
    })
}
    
render() {
    return (
        <DefaultLayout>
        <div className="friendsoverviewcontainer">
            <h1>Our community ({this.state.friends.length} registered users)</h1>
            <form className="friends">               
                <div className="titlepart">
                    <label className="friendlabel" htmlFor="friend">Search for Users :</label><br></br>
                    <input className="friendform" type="text" name="friend" value={this.state.friend} placeholder="Type a username here!" onChange={this.searchFriends}></input>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div className="friendsboxes" >
                {
                    this.state.searchFriends.map(friend =>
                        <div key={friend._id}>
                            <Frienddetail 
                                key={friend._id}
                                id={friend._id}
                                username={friend.username}
                                location={friend.location}
                                innerCircle={this.addToInnerCircle}
                                peopleFollow={this.addPeopleFollow}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )   
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

**Specific Frienddetail component**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Frienddetail.css'

class Frienddetail extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="friendbox">
                    <img className="imagedaredevilspicdetail" src="/images/profileimage.png" alt="picturesetting" />
                    <p className="friend">{this.props.username}</p>
                    <p className="friend">{this.props.location}</p>
                    <button className="followbutton" onClick={(e) => this.props.peopleFollow(this.props.id)}>Follow user!</button>
                    <button className="friendbutton" onClick={(e)=> this.props.innerCircle(this.props.id)}>Add to inner circle!</button>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Frienddetail
```

---

**usermodel**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    location: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    friends: [String],
    error: String
})

const User = mongoose.model("users",userSchema)

module.exports = User;
```

---

**Backend**

```
// add peopleYouFollow
router.post("/friends", (req,res) => {
  console.log("thisishappening")
  let iduser = getUser()._id 
  User
  .findByIdAndUpdate({_id:iduser})
  .then((response) => {
    res.json(response)
    console.log("thisishappening")
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to suggest some changes to the `Schema` as you are storing `Array of String`, you should be storing `Array of ObjectId` because you are storing `objectId _id`, you can change your Schema like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    location: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    friends: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    error: String
})
```

You might have to drop your collection and build it again.

I'm not sure if you are receiving both ID's, if not you might need to update your axios request to send all the data. Assuming you are receiving both `ID's` and are not able to add anything to the `friends` array?

That's because you are not adding anything in your array, in order to do that you need to use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator like this-

```
 router.post("/friends", (req,res) => {
  let iduser = getUser()._id 
  User.update({_id:iduser},{$push:{friends: ID of Friend here!}})
  .then((response) => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

I didn't go through all of your code because you posted too much but this is the gist of what you are looking for!

Comment: thanks man! just one small extra question. How do I get access to the "ID of friend"? req.body.id? I am passing it in as idpeopleyoufollow in the front-end but don't how to capture it in the backend?

Comment: any idea about this?

Comment: If you can post what object you are getting in your backend from your frontend then I can suggest something, without that its very hard to guess

Comment: how can I figure out what object I am getting in my backend?

Comment: Inside `router.post` do `console.log(req.body)`